# Add Framework dynamically in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I add framework at run time, so that I can access it globally in the project?

If I'm adding manually going to save my location, then I am getting below warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F <my drive location ...>
```

Also it is not accessible globally.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Please explain in more detail. "How can add to parent project, that can available across project" - What does this even mean ?

Answer (score 1):

I also got similar issue because i am getting my framework end of build in my project : then i found solution:

add your project to framwork where you want :
**Drag and Drop**  then go to :

> **Build Settings**>> Search Paths >>Framework Search Path>>Change path to  ./ (selecting recursive.)

**or**

> **Build Settings**>> Search Paths >>Library Search Path>>Change path to  ./ (selecting recursive.)

**If that will not help then replace ./ to**

> **$(PROJECT_DIR)/**  => for getting project path dynamically . ../ => to go back to desire project folder

**EX:**

> $(PROJECT_DIR)/..//Pinterest.embeddedframework